# Entity Framework mapping with link table

Tags: c#, mapping, entity, dbcontext

I have db structure with 2 tables and 1 link table for relation zero to many:

```
Clients {
   Id number (primary key), 
   ...
}

Solutions {
  Id number (primary key),
  ...
}

ClientSolutions {
  Id_Solution number (primary key)
  Id_Client number, 
}
```

Client have zero or many solutions, Solution have zero or one client.

Fluent mapping in context:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<client>()
        .HasMany(u => u.solutions).WithOptional(x=>x.client)
        .Map(x => x.MapKey(new[] { "Id_Client","Id_Solution" })        
        .ToTable("ClientSolutions"));
```

Test case:

```
var q = from c in context.clients
        from s in c.solutions
        select { c.id, s.id }
```

The declared type of navigation property client.solutions is not compatible with the result of the specified navigation

What i doing wrong? I can't change the structure of the database :(

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the relationship table to do this, i suggest you to do something like that:

```
 public class Client
 {
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<Solution> Solutions { get; set; }
 }
 public class Solution
 {
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public long? ClientId { get; set; }
   public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
 }
```

**Client** Entity Configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
    .HasMany(c => c.Solutions).WithOptional()
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.ClientId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

**Solution** Entity Configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Solution>()
     .HasOptional(t => t.Client)
     .WithMany(c => c.Solutions)
     .HasForeignKey(s => s.ClientId)
     .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

I hope to be clear and helpful, X)

Comment: I can't change structure of database. For relationship i need use table ClientSolutions

Comment: Hum, but is a unnecessary table for this kind of relationship.